# Terminal CMD de PHPStorm me escribe caracteres raros

Tags: cmd, línea-de-comandos, phpstorm

Al intentar ejecutar unos comandos donde debo utilizar `\` y seleccionar con ***Shift + "Flechas"*** me introduce caracteres raros como `Þ\` o `"02D"`, antes esto no ocurria y se esta volviendo tedioso cuando debo ejecutar comandos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]